# jQuery empty()/remove() makes page jump

Tags: jquery

I have a monitoring website which shows "who is logged in" and their "state" (online/away/etc.).

They are basically wrapped near the bottom of my page with:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="telecaster_agentenstatus" class="telecaster">
            <tr>
                <td id="free_agents">
                </td>
                <td id="acw_agents">
                </td>
                <td id="pause_agents">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="telecaster_agentenstatus_start">
                <td id="agentenstatuus" colspan="3">
                    <div class="agent_telecaster_container"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

So all "agents" get into the div with the class "agent_telecaster_container".
I append as many divs as I need  with:

```
for (nameAgent in supervisionagents.group[0].agent) {
            //$("#agentenstatuus").append('<div class="agent_telecaster">'+nameAgent+'</div>'); 
            counter++;

            if (supervisionagents.group[0].agent[nameAgent].stateCurrent.description == "idle") 
            {
                $(".agent_telecaster_container").append('<div id="agent'+counter+'" class="agent_telecaster"><img src="images/icons/box_green_12x12.png">&nbsp;' + nameAgent + '</div>');
            }
```

Which gets called over and over again.

What I need is to "clear" the  with its content because it can be that every second someone gets offline or online.

So far this can be possible with a simple:

```
$('.agent_telecaster_container').empty() / .remove();
```

But what then happens is that if I move my view / scrollbar to view some things underneath that table, with every reload (every sec.) it jumps back to this .
I guess this happens because of the remove / empty and this element gets deleted but new content gets in.

Has anybody any idea on how to prevent the jumping? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried hiding the element first, and then removing it?
.hide().remove(); Or try a fadeOut() then call remove() in the callback:

```
.fadeOut('fast',function( $('.agent_telecaster_container').remove(); ));
```

Comment: A nice idea that maybe could make a nice view of this "event" :) I will keep it in mind and have a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your main container for contacts fixed by height and add wertical scrollbar. Then nothing jumps.

Comment: But with this dynamic content how should I set a fixed height, or does it grow when it gets higher?

Comment: Nope, thats just adding sry. Because they can get offline and disappear in my Object they must erase on that div container too.

Comment: But its just a sample how <div> content changes! Add id to any div you attach to div vith id "container" and remove it by id if some user logged out! Looks like we cannot understand each other...

Answer (score 0):

This works fine :-)

```
$('#agentenstatuus').css('height',$('.agent_telecaster_container').height());
```

at the end of every loop :-)
This sets the table's cell to the height of the div container and no jump arounds come up!

My before edited mistake was because of a CSS mistake in my .css file.