# Jquery page moves back to top on checkbox change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page moves back up to the top when you click any of the buttons under the second "Clients" heading here: http://kodiakgroup.com/clients.php

I have tried the `preventDefault` function as well as `return false` per suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976753/jquery-click-brings-me-to-top-of-page-but-i-want-to-stay-where-i-am) in the on change functions you can see below. See what I can do to prevent this behavior?

Part I changed:

```
//Toggle select all/deselect function
        $('#vertical-filters input').change(function (e) {
                $('.selectAllBoxes').prop('checked', false);
                getCustomers();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
        }); 

        $('.selectAllBoxes').change(function (e) {
                $('#vertical-filters input').prop('checked', false);
                getCustomers();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
        });
```

All of the javascript:

```
$(function () {
        $('.selectAllBoxes').prop('checked', true);//Set checkboxes as checked by default
        getCustomers(); //Initially call all customers

        function getCustomers()
        {   
            $('ul#customers').html('');//empty list
            var definedCategoryArray=new Array();
            var categoriesPlural= new Array();
            var customerSplit=new Array();


            for(var x=0; x< $('#vertical-filters input').length; x++){
                var thisItem=$('#vertical-filters input')[x];
                var thisItemName=$(thisItem).attr('id');
                if($('.selectAllBoxes').is(':checked')){
                    definedCategoryArray[thisItemName]=true;
                }
                else{
                    if ($(thisItem).is(':checked'))
                        definedCategoryArray[thisItemName]=true;
                    else
                        definedCategoryArray[thisItemName]=false;
                }
            }


            $.getJSON('customers.json', function(data) {
                for(var index in definedCategoryArray){ //cycle through categories array
                    for(var i=0; i<data.customers.length; i++){ //cycle through json data
                        if (definedCategoryArray[index]==true){//if the value in the array is true (item checked)
                            //console.log(data.customers[i].customerName+ ' : ' + data.customers[i].category);
                                if(data.customers[i].category.indexOf(',') != -1) //if there is more than one category, detect the comma seperating them
                                    categoriesPlural = data.customers[i].category.split(',');   
                                else //there is only one category
                                    categoriesPlural[0]=data.customers[i].category;
                                for (var y = 0; y<categoriesPlural.length; y++){
                                        //console.log(categoriesPlural[y]);
                                        if(categoriesPlural[y] == index){ //match category (from definedCategoryArray index) to items in json object to parse
                                            $('ul#customers').append('<li class="' +data.customers[i].customerName.replace(/\s+/g, '-') + '" id="'+data.customers[i].customerName.replace(/\s+/g, '-')+'"><a href="'+ data.customers[i].link +'" title="'+ data.customers[i].customerName +'" target="_blank"><img src="'+ data.customers[i].imageLink +'" alt="'+ data.customers[i].customerName +'" /></a></li>');
                                            checkDuplicates(data.customers[i].customerName.replace(/\s+/g, '-'));
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).fail(function() { console.log( "error" ); });
        }

        function checkDuplicates(customerName){
            for(var x=0; x< $('#customers li').length; x++){//loop through clients already on the page to prevent duplicates
                var thisClient=$('#customers li')[x];
                var thisClientName=$(thisClient).attr('id');
                    if(thisClientName == customerName){
                        var superClient1=$('.'+customerName)[1];
                        var superClient2=$('.'+customerName)[2];
                        if (superClient1)
                            $(superClient1).css('display','none');
                        if(superClient2)
                            $(superClient2).css('display','none');
                        //console.log(customerName + '=' + thisClientName + ' emptied');
                    }
                }
        }

        //Toggle select all/deselect function
        $('#vertical-filters input').change(function (e) {
                $('.selectAllBoxes').prop('checked', false);
                getCustomers();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
        }); 

        $('.selectAllBoxes').change(function (e) {
                $('#vertical-filters input').prop('checked', false);
                getCustomers();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
        }); 

    });
```

Comment: When I clicked the link to the Kodiak Group page it threw an error on load. The error may be preventing your javascript from being loaded properly. If the javascript is not loaded it will not call the preventDefault event on click.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys! Both were good answers so I wasn't sure which one to mark. I actually just set a min-height on the container and it fixed it! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually going back to top, but you are removing items. The page is shrinking and scroll disapear then you add item and the page expand without scrolling back.

An easy hack to do is to fix the heigh of the `ul` before removing items and then remove the attribute style. Like that :

```
$('#vertical-filters input').change(function (e) {
    $('.selectAllBoxes').prop('checked', false);
    $('ul#customers').height($('ul#customers').height()); //fix the height
    getCustomers();
    $('ul#customers').removeAttr('style'); //Reset the height
});
```

Repeat for all the `.change()` functions.

It is not tested but in theory, it should work

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are removing the content from the `ul#customers` container, check this line in your HTML

```
function getCustomers()
{   
    $('ul#customers').html('');//empty list
    ...
}
```

There are some workarounds to avoid this scroll, you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336991/jquery-empty-remove-makes-page-jump)

Answer (score 0):

As another answer here suggests, try setting a height on the `ul`. This would be my approach:

```
function getCustomers() {   
    var $customers = $('ul#customers');
    $customers.css('height', $customers.height());
    $customers.html(''); //empty list

    // the rest of your getCustomers() function

    // at the very end, remove the height
    $customers.css('height', '');
}
```

So, you start with explicitly setting a height on the `ul`. This will keep it from collapsing. Then, you can empty it and add in the new content. At the very end, you remove the height, and the `ul` will collapse to whatever height its contents require.

This will probably still be a little jolting. You could consider animating the height either with [jQuery $.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [CSS3 animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)