# Jquery onchange click causes browser to go back to top in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I posted a question a few days ago regarding the browser scroller moving back up to the top when the jquery onchange click function occurred here: [Jquery page moves back to top on checkbox change function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487706/jquery-page-moves-back-to-top-on-checkbox-change-function). I resolved it by setting the min-height of the container, but now I realize that that did not fix the issue in Internet Explorer. Any ideas?

Comment: You should go back to the original question - are you able to unmark the current answer?

Comment: I posted an answer on your original question. Try that out and let us know what happens.