# Page jumps on checkbox click even with javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, html

A while ago you guys helped me with a page jump issue on [this page](http://www.kodiakgroup.com/clients/) in [this forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487706/jquery-page-moves-back-to-top-on-checkbox-change-function). I will be referring to the styled checkboxes under "Clients." Well a while back I just set the min-height on the changing container and it then prevented the page jump, but no longer does (for an unknown reason). Well, I went ahead and put window.scrollTo(0,1400) in my function, but it doesn't center the styled checkboxes correctly on IE so now I'm back to trying to figure out why the page jumps.

The weirdest thing though.. the page jumps when clicking one of the styled checkboxes even if you disable javascript (in chrome developer tool settings and then refresh). **Why would a checkbox with javascript turned off cause a page jump?**

Comment: How do you generate the clients full list?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look on your source code I couldn't figure out why do you pull data using json on each click? does the clients change LIVE?

What i mean is you can list all your clients without Using Get Json or any kind of live query and then add a class for their related respective verticals.

For example for Services and healthcare,

**css**

```
#verticals li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    background-color: #97ceff;
    color: black;
    border-radius:2px; 
    margin-right:10px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#verticals li.activevertical{
    background-color: #2f7fc7;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**html output**

```
 <!-- list verticals options !-->
    <ul id="verticals">
       <li id="service">Services</li>
       <li id="healthcare">Healthcare</li>
    </ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
    <ul id="customers" class="">
       <!-- Add filter class here in the <li> add filter_ before vertical kind !-->
           <li class="filter_service">Ecova</li>
           <li class="filter_service">HP</li>
           <li class="filter_service">Gartner</li>
           <li class="filter_healthcare">Henry Schein</li>
           <li class="filter_healthcare">GE Healthcare</li>
           <li class="filter_healthcare">BerylHealth</li>
    <!-- and if a vertical can be in two categories add both vertical classes !-->
           <li class="filter_healthcare filter_service">BerylHealth Show in Service and Healthcare</li>
    </ul>
```

**jQuery** : very short version

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#verticals li").on('click', function(){
        var filterli  = ".filter_"+$(this).attr("id");
        $("#customers li").hide();
        $("#verticals li").removeClass('activevertical');
        $(this).addClass('activevertical');
        $(filterli).show();
    });
});
```

check it out at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HKf82/10/)

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I already wrote this a while ago and I'm just trying to figure out why the page would jump when you click a checkbox (even with javascript disabled which means the list won't even be populated).

Comment: for  one this also makes it jump window.scrollTo(0,1400), i do not  know how do you disable javascript, it must be enabled somehwere

Comment: No I mean when I disable it in console.. just going to that page, the javascript will work. I'm simply asking why an HTML checkbox with all javascript turned off would cause a page jump.